# React turns a state key into a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a relatively simple React app using redux architecture, and for some reason one of the state properties is being changed to a promise.

I am eventually going to try to pull data from a database to use as data, but I am starting with hard-coded data. I cannot figure out why in the world the `Charts` key, by the time it reaches the layout/charts/index component why it has changed to be a Promise? I haven't included any api/async functionality in my app from what I can tell. I have included all the files that I think are relevant to the issue. I have tried console.logging the state in various places and I cannot seem to identify when or why the state decides to change to a promise. Any help would be much appreciated.

**GitHub Repo of project [here](https://github.com/cooper-campbell/reactCharts).**

app.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import Root from './containers/Root';

const initialState = {
    Charts: {
        PieChart: {
            data: {
                failed: false,
                isfetching: false,
                contains: null
            },
            msg: 'Preparing to fetch',
            width: '100%',
            height: '30vh',
            options: {
                title: 'Lateness of things',
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                titlePosition: 'none',
                pieHole: 0.7,
                pieSliceTextStyle: {
                    color: 'black',
                },
            }
        },
        BarChart: {
            chartType: 'BarChart',
            width: '100%',
            height: '30vh',
            data: [
                ['Type', 'On time', 'Late', { role: 'annotation' }],
                ['Child', 4, 18, ''],
                ['Fire/EV/Body', 18, 21, ''],
                ['Truck', 49, 92, ''],
                ['Off-Highway/UTV', 18, 62, ''],
                ['Bus/Coach/WTORS', 5, 8, ''],
                ['Other', 11, 23, '']
            ],
            options: {
                isStacked: true,
                height: 300,
                legend: {position: 'top'},
                hAxis: {minValue: 0}
            }
        }
    }
};
const store = configureStore(initialState);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
    <AppContainer>
        <Root store={store} history={history}/>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
        const NewRoot = require('./containers/Root').default;
        render(
            <AppContainer>
                <NewRoot store={store} history={history}/>
            </AppContainer>,
            document.getElementById('root'),
        );
    });
}
```

reducer.js

```
import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const Charts = async (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.PIE_DATA_LOADING:
            return {...state, PieChart: {isfetching: true, contains: null, failed: false}};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    Charts,
    routing,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

container/Charts.js

```
import MainChart from './../components/layout/charts';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { startPieDataLoad } from './../actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        Charts: state.Charts,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadingPieChartData: () => {
            return dispatch(startPieDataLoad());
        }
    };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainChart);
```

components/layout/charts/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import TotalChanges from './TotalChanges';
import ChangesByFunctionalGroups from './ChangesByFunctionalGroups';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MainChart = ({Charts}) => {
    const BarChartData = Charts.BarChart;
    const PieChartData = Charts.PieChart;
    const PieChart = (!PieChartData.data.isfetching === false) ? (<TotalChanges chartData={PieChart} />) : (<div>{PieChartData.msg}</div>);
    return (
        <div className={classNames('mainWindow')}>
            <div className={classNames('row')}>
                <div className={classNames('col-sm-4')}>
                    {PieChart}
                </div>
                <div className={classNames('col-sm-4')}>
                    <ChangesByFunctionalGroups chartData={BarChartData} />
                </div>
                <div className={classNames('col-sm-4')}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

MainChart.propTypes = {
    Charts: PropTypes.object,
    loadingPieChartData: PropTypes.func
};

export default MainChart;
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState
    );
};
```

action.js

```
import * as types from './types';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
export function example(filter) {
    return {
        type: types.FILTER,
        filter,
    };
}

export function startPieDataLoad() {
    return {
        type: types.PIE_DATA_LOADING
    };
};

export function finishPieDataLoad(data) {
    return {
        type: (data.err === true) ? types.PIE_DATA_LOADED_FAIL : types.PIE_DATA_LOADED_SUCCESS,
        data: data.msg
    };
};


export function fetchPieChartData() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(startPieDataLoad);
        return fetch('http://localhost:3001/cm/piechart').then(response => response.json()).then(json => dispatch(finishPieDataLoad(json)));
    };
};
```

Comment: Doesn't `dispatch` return a promise?

Comment: can you post your store config (a fiddle/repo would be really nice) ? i think this is a middle-ware issue. @CooperCampbell

Comment: it shouldn't by my understanding, unless you are implementing thunk Middleware or something. Either way, my app doesn't even have time to fire the function that returns a promise, the first time the component receives Charts it is a promise. Also, I don't think that dispatch returning a promise would mess with the Charts key in the state, would it? @DanielB

Comment: @John I added the config file, it is simple, I am not even using Middleware at the moment because that was my first inclination too. thanks for the help, and I don't currently have a repo for it. I can work on getting it on github though If you message me directly I can send you a copy of the full app. Sorry for the  inconvenience

Comment: Can you show us your `startPieDataLoad()` action creator? I don't see it here.

Comment: @CooperCampbell I see that, thanks. I'm going to request you send me a copy. I'm not 100% sure why its returning a promise, but i see one or two things that might make it act weird and that could be the cause of the promise being returned.

Comment: @radiovisual I added all the actions, thanks. I don't believe any of the actions are actually being called though. Which is part of the reason why I am so confused.

Comment: @John Thank you so much, how would I get that to you?

Comment: This might be tricky to diagnose without it being setup somewhere. Can you either load this sample to JSFiddle or JSBin or put up this sample on GitHub so we can run the code?

Comment: @radiovisual I made a quick repo for it. https://github.com/cooper-campbell/reactCharts. Thank you for the help

Comment: @John I made a github repository for it. https://github.com/cooper-campbell/reactCharts Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I was declaring the action as an async function which caused it to return a promise. I hadn't realized that was there which is why it took me three hours to find it.

The issue is in reducer.js

```
import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const Charts = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.PIE_DATA_LOADING:
            return {...state, PieChart: {isfetching: true, contains: null, failed: false}};
        default:
            return state;
    }
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    Charts,
    routing,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Note the lack of *async* after the Charts =

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer. Good work buddy.

Comment: It won't let me for another two days, thank you so much again for helping me with this. I was going crazy staring at it wondering why in the world it was deciding to randomly return promises. Are you sure you don't want credit for it? @John

Comment: Post the code that fixed your problem here before you mark this as the correct answer, so that anyone who might find this post in the future can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. In Redux, you never mutate state. In your reducer use object.assign

```
    case types.PIE_DATA_LOADING:
        return {...state,
            Object.assign({}, {PieChart: {isfetching: true, contains: null, failed: false}})
```

Comment: Nvm. Ill look at the repo, and debug it. Then ill post all my suggested changes.

Comment: Thanks, also i thought the spread syntax negated the need to use Object.assign()? Ill make the change anyway

Comment: I found the error. It was the reducer that has the pesky Async that i didnt realize my friend added. This caused the function to return a promise in place of the new state. Thanks for helping me and for looking at it, and I hope I didn't waste too much of your time. If you want to post an answer suggesting removing the async keyword I'll select it as right

Comment: @CooperCampbell. Haha, not its okay. I haven't really had a chance to look at it yet. You should post your own answer. If you ran into any problems, send me a PM, or my contact info is here https://github.com/AndrewKralovec

Comment: You don't necessarily need `Object.assign()` if you are using the spread operator correctly. But @CooperCampbell , I think you might have a syntax issue with your use of the spread operator in the reducer returning the `state.Chart.PieChart` object.

Comment: @radiovisual Good point, since this is react he will be using babel, and so as long as he uses the operator syntax he'll be fine. Object.assign() was a standard when i first learned Redux.